# how to fix "hadoop is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file"

Tags: hadoop

i am setting up hadoop on a windows 10 machine. when i try to run the hadoop namenode -format command i get the error "hadoop is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file".

i have tried to rename my folder containing the hadoop files and adding the new path to my environment variable but it didn't help

C:\Users\HP>hadoop namenode -format
'hadoop' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

i expect the namenode to be formatted but iam getting the error above